# Better to use coil relay or remanent core relay for hi-fi audio switching?

Tags: relay, latching-relay

I am working on a hi-fi audio component that needs to switch line level signal. If I am using electromechanical relays to do this, on the assumption that that will provide the least effect on the signal, then I would seem to have a choice between two different kinds of latching relays. One is the coil-based relay, and the other is the remanent core relay. Which of these would be the best choice to minimize any effect the relay might have on the signal?

Note that mainly concerned only about the steady state effects of the relay. Effects that would occur as the contact goes on or off are less important.

Comment: Steady state it should not matter, the coil should be DC, and no change in flux means no induced voltage anywhere else... The initial pulse of driving a relay may make noise... Depending on system gain and sensitivity

Answer (score 2):

There is capacitance between the coil and the contacts, and current variation in the coil will also create an AC magnetic field around the relay. So you should make sure the voltage you use to feed the coils is well regulated and without ripple. No need to overdo it, a LM317 is fine, or you can use the +15V for the opamps to feed a +12V relay with some RC filtering to make sure the switching spikes don't get into the opamp supply. But don't use unregulated DC from the smoothing caps.

Likewise, make sure noise from the microcontroller doesn't couple through the IOs and into the relays. You can do that easily with a RC filter, or even safer, put the micro to sleep with the clock off and a wake-on-pin-change interrupt to wake it up when required. If your micro is powered by a 5V switching converter, it might not be a good idea to use that 5V for the relay coils, as the switching noise could couple into the signal.

You can use signal/reed relays, make sure it doesn't have a wetting current spec, as the contacts that have such a spec require some current for cleaning.

I'd use bistable relays just to use less idle power, but that depends on cost. Reeds also use very little power.

You can use FET switches too. Their RdsON varies with voltage, and that can cause distortion. If they're on the + input of an opamp that draws negligible current, then changes in RdsON won't cause distortion. If they're on the - input of an inverting opamp, there will be no change in voltage, so again, no problem. If you use an opto-FET then it'll have constant Vgs so no RdsON variation (but that's more expensive than CMOS switches).

They do have some capacitance though, which can cause crosstalk, so you should check if that's a problem, and maybe use some SPDT FET switches to short the unused inputs, or something like that.

Comment: What you say about Rdson varying with voltage only applies to the non-isolated CMOS analog switches. Optically isolated  NMOS switches have constant Rdson because they have no reference potential other than the signal itself. Off-capacitance for small current types is single pF or below, so not really worse than relays

Answer (score 1):

In general either would do the job, the 'inrush' in the circuit does more 'pop' than the inductive noise. For instrumentation signals magnetic latching relays are often used because they don't heat up (and heating could change the contact properties… think thermocouple effect). Also reed relays are made exactly for that purpose: only signal, no significant current and rhodium plated contacts in inert gas.

Comment: Good point about reed Relais. I completely forgot about them as I haven't used any in ages. Personally nowadays, I would still prefer a small optomos due to easier drive, smaller size&cost.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by MadHatter there is no induction effect other than during switching, so it won't matter.

I wouldn't trust relays in general with a low voltage low current signal and use an opto-Mosfet switch. The reason is that some relays have minimum load ratings below which they are not ohmic and highly nonlinear. I don't know if this applies to all relays. But when I hear HiFi, I wouldn't take risks and use a semiconductor switch.

also having a large electromagnet nearby sensitive signal sounds like another needless risk. A semi switch doesn't have that.

Comment: the purists would say that opto switches harm the signal :D in practice you can simply use reed or signal relays (which can actually cost *more* of an opto switch). They can handle microvolt signals without issues.